# Postgres providing default to LAG makes the colum NULL

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I've got the query below:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        b.provider_id,
        b.customer_id customer_id,
        c.email email,
        c.created_at created_at,
        c.deleted_at deleted_at,
        count(*) bookings_count
    FROM
        bookings b
        LEFT JOIN appointments a ON a.id = b.appointment_id
        LEFT JOIN customers c ON c.id = b.customer_id
    WHERE
        a.appointment_channel_id = 13
        AND email LIKE 'foo%'
    GROUP BY
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5
)
SELECT
    *,
    LAG(deleted_at, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY created_at DESC)
FROM
    CTE
```

My aim with this query is to find out successive duplicate accounts both of which are not deleted. So that I  partition by `email` and using the `LAG` function I check the `deleted_at` column of the last row, if that's `NULL` then that means a new account was created without the previous one being deleted.

The result I get from the query above is
[image]

But then as you can see , since the default for `LAG` is `NULL`, it assumes that the very first account created also has its `is_prev_acc_deleted` `FALSE` but there were no accounts before that.

To overcome that I use the same query but I give a default of a random timestamp to `LAG`.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        b.provider_id,
        b.customer_id customer_id,
        c.email email,
        c.created_at created_at,
        c.deleted_at deleted_at,
        count(*) bookings_count
    FROM
        bookings b
        LEFT JOIN appointments a ON a.id = b.appointment_id
        LEFT JOIN customers c ON c.id = b.customer_id
    WHERE
        a.appointment_channel_id = 13
        AND email LIKE 'foo%'
    GROUP BY
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5
)
SELECT
    *,
    LAG(deleted_at, 1, now()::timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY created_at DESC) IS NOT NULL AS is_prev_acc_deleted
FROM
    CTE
```

Only difference in the query above is that I've added a default to `LAG` which is `now()::timestamp`. After running that query, the result I get is:

[image]

I do not really know why the `deleted_at` columns become `NULL` in this case and the intermediate rows disappear.

I've tried to give you a link to reproduce the same thing but I couldn't reproduce it here:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=bgT8Jjc9Kn

Maybe it's because I've only created one table with all the information? Not sure. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `now()::timestamp` can be simplified to `localtimestamp`

Comment: The default value is only applied if the _row_ does not exist (e.g. in the first row of the window), it's not used to replace NULL values in the column itself. If you want to get a different value than `null` you need to use `coalesce()`

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Images are frowned upon here for the reasons outlined in [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530). Please repost as text.

Comment: Please post data as *text*, never as image. Always declare your version of Postgres. And formulate a clear question.

Comment: Disappearing rows make no sense. Database corruption (unlikely) or something is not as presented here.

Comment: Sorry, I just couldn't really properly copy the results so I decided to paste as screenshot but I'll change that. That's actually why I used the default value, so that for the first row (I mean the oldest account) would have `is_prev_acc_deleted` as `TRUE` otherwise I get `FALSE` which is not correct.

Comment: I do not really know how else to explain it but I've already shared the query I am using and the results I get. That's all I did to get these results. One more thing is I am using [Sisense Periscope Data](https://www.sisense.com/blog/periscope-data-is-now-sisense-for-cloud-data-teams/) to run the queries, if that's helpful in any way.

Comment: You need to create a dbfiddle.uk with some sample data that shows the problem, otherwise it's just a guessing game.

Comment: Could you please form a complete question. Currently your summary only contains observations and not what you are expecting. E.g. _**How can I achieve a result set that contains .... based on my previous query .... which includes ...?**_  And then include two or three example records. Thanks.